# understand about Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I have read *Introduction to real analysis* by Manfred Stoll. And I am confused about this question:
Construct a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ converges for each $x\in[0,1]$ but that $\{f_{n}\}$ does not converge uniformly on any measurable set $E\subset[0,1]$ with $\lambda([0,1] - E)=0$.

Is it a contradiction with Egorov's Theorem?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't contradict Egorov.  Egorov says if $\epsilon > 0$ you can remove a set of measure $< \epsilon$ and get uniform convergence on the rest.  Here the removed set would need to have measure $0$.